# How to start recording video?AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer

Tags: ios, swift, ip-camera

I am setting up a custom camera with a previewlayert.everything works.I set the orientation and everything.
I would like to ask how to set up autofocus?
And second,how to start the camera to record a video?(because yet it just shows what the front camera shows,you see you)...but i want to startvthe recording.

I would prefere code in Swift,but its ok in Objective C and i translate it.Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From [Apple's Audio/Video capture documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html),

**Saving to a Movie File:**

You save movie data to a file using an AVCaptureMovieFileOutput object. (AVCaptureMovieFileOutput is a concrete subclass of AVCaptureFileOutput, which defines much of the basic behavior.) You can configure various aspects of the movie file output, such as the maximum duration of a recording, or its maximum file size. You can also prohibit recording if there is less than a given amount of disk space left.

```
AVCaptureMovieFileOutput *aMovieFileOutput = [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc] init];

CMTime maxDuration = <#Create a CMTime to represent the maximum duration#>;
aMovieFileOutput.maxRecordedDuration = maxDuration;
aMovieFileOutput.minFreeDiskSpaceLimit = <#An appropriate minimum given the quality of the movie format and the duration#>;
The resolution and bit rate for the output depend on the capture session’s sessionPreset. The video encoding is typically H.264 and audio encoding is typically AAC. The actual values vary by device.*

AVCaptureMovieFileOutput *aMovieFileOutput = <#Get a movie file output#>;
NSURL *fileURL = <#A file URL that identifies the output location#>;
[aMovieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:fileURL recordingDelegate:<#The delegate#>];
```

In the implementation of captureOutput:didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:fromConnections:error:, the delegate might write the resulting movie to the Camera Roll album. It should also check for any errors that might have occurred.